# Why this regular expression is not working

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

I am using python 2.7 with scrapy .20

I have this test

> 0552121152, +97143321090

I want to get the value before the `comma` and the value after it.

My regular expression is

`\s*(.*),` for the one before

and `,\s*(.*)` for the one after

in both ways I got the **whole test.**

**why please?**

#### Edit

For who need a full details, here it is:

This is the page I am scraping http://www.justproperty.com/apartments/old-town/1092713-amazing-2br-apartment-in-the-old-town-island-with-a-burj-khalifa-and-address-hotel-view.html

and this is my scrapy code in cmd in shell:

```
    s =sel.xpath("normalize-space(.//span[@class='content_agent']/span[last()]/span[2]/text())")
 s.re(r'\s*(.*),')
```

#### Note

I am not asking about the solution to get these values, I am asking about why my mentioned-regular expression is not working

Comment: Your regex seems to be working fine. See [here](http://regex101.com/r/uO2rD7)

Comment: @Kamehameha the website you provided is not working

Comment: re.search(r'\s*(.*),(.*)', yourstring).groups try that, although I'd replace the all character wild card match like . to be more specific like say \d+ or something.

Comment: @Joe thanks to your comment, I am asking why my regular expssion is not working, not what is the correct regular expression

Comment: @Kamehameha yes the website works, why it works with you not with me pelase?

Comment: What do you mean? It *is* working. I just tested both your regex *combined* and it's returning both numbers just fine.

Comment: @Nanashi I stated on the question that `not working` means that the results is the whole text, not the numbers before the comma and the numbers after the comma

Comment: It seems that the regular expression I mentioned is working, @Kamehameha please write an answer to accept it

Comment: Check my answer below and try to reproduce it. If it works, then it's just a matter of transferring the logic to your code. Otherwise, well, I don't know what else, really.

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli accept one of the answers that're already written. There are some which allow you use only one regex to do your job. Just out of curiosity, what was the error and how'd figure it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing it this way:

```
import re

string = "0552121152, +97143321090"
pattern = re.compile(r"\s*(.*),\s*(.*)")

print pattern.search(string).groups()
```

Result:

```
('0552121152', '+97143321090')
[Finished in 0.3s]
```

The only difference might be because I used the `.groups()` method, that's why I'm getting it. If you can reproduce this on your end, then ***it's not your regular expression that is wrong*** but your coding style.

Other than that, I fail to see how the regex fails at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, +1, It seems that I had another problem that prevents me from getting the text, my mentioned regular expressionisworking fine

Comment: That can explain it, really. Check to see if the XPath is getting the text correctly. Even if you have `normalize-space` up there, not all whitespaces might have been removed. Try adding `.strip()` at the end of your selector, then run the regex again. It might stick after that.

Answer (score 2):

That because `.` matches also `,` and it's a greedy selection. Use something like more specific like `[^,]` or `\d` instead of `.` symbol.

Comment: No i don't think that. because I have put the `,` in my regular expression, so it should stop at that `comma`

Comment: @AdamSmith Sorry for being late my friend, I forget to tell you that I tried to use the `[^,]` but I still got the whole text.

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Hmm then your input and output isn't what you're giving us, because several people confirm that they cannot reproduce your results.

Comment: @AdamSmith I found that the regular expssion that I mentioned in the questions was working from the first place, I just had another problem that prevents me to take the text. Thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would store the part before the comma in `\1` and the part after the comma in `\2`

```
/(\s?[\d]+)(?:[, ]+)([+\d]+)/
```

This looks for an optional number of whitespace characters followed by some digits.  Then it looks for either a space or comma (or both) followed by another string made up of a character class of numbers and/or a plus sign.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my question is why my mentioned regular expression is not working, I can find another way to solve it, but I don't know why my regular expression is not working